# switch statement in Swift language, what's the execution order in the case clause that has a where in it?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Let say we have below pseudo code snippet:

```
switch some_variable {
    case let v where <condition_checking>:
        do_something...
}
```

As I understand, when code execution goes into switch, it first goes with the first case statement (we only have one). Then it checks the condition_checking part and if it's true, then the let part will be execute and do_something will have a chance to run. Is that correct?

I ask this question it's because I saw below code snippet from Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html (the last part of the page):

```
let finalSquare = 25
var board = [Int](count: finalSquare + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
board[03] = +08; board[06] = +11; board[09] = +09; board[10] = +02
board[14] = -10; board[19] = -11; board[22] = -02; board[24] = -08
var square = 0
var diceRoll = 0

gameLoop: while square != finalSquare {
    if ++diceRoll == 7 { diceRoll = 1 }
    switch square + diceRoll {
    case finalSquare:
        // diceRoll will move us to the final square, so the game is over
        break gameLoop
    case let newSquare where newSquare > finalSquare:
        // diceRoll will move us beyond the final square, so roll again
        continue gameLoop
    default:
        // this is a valid move, so find out its effect
        square += diceRoll
        square += board[square]
    }
}
println("Game over!")
```

Note this statement `case let newSquare where newSquare > finalSquare:`, the `newSquare` is defined by `let` in this `case` statement. The `where` is using `newSquare` directly, and it seems the `let` part is first executed then the `where` part. This is not what I've understood about it. Can anyone help to clarify please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I understand, when code execution goes into switch, it first goes with the first case statement (we only have one). Then it checks the condition_checking part and if it's true, then the let part will be execute and do_something will have a chance to run. Is that correct?

I think you misunderstand. In this code:

```
case let newSquare where newSquare > finalSquare:
```

The execution order would be:

- bind `newSquare` to the value of `square + diceRoll`.
- Evaluate `newSquare > finalSquare`
- If true, execute block with `newSquare` binding

This line:

```
case finalSquare:
```

can be thought of as shorthand for:

```
case let __temp where __temp == finalSquare:
```

(without the creation of a real `__temp` symbol)

Comment: Thank you. Very clearly explained. It's confusing that the pattern matching part is just creating a variable. I'm clear now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

First the code will match the `expression` to the case `pattern`. Which in this case is `let newSquare` it will then execute the `where` condition which is known as the `guard` expression.

So, think of the code as matching the case pattern and then further validating using a where condition.

**First:** Match the case pattern `let newSquare` which simply assigns the value to the variable newSquare.

**Second:** Check the `guard` expression `newSquare > finalSquare`

> A switch case can optionally contain a guard expression after each
>   pattern. A guard expression is introduced by the keyword where
>   followed by an expression, and is used to provide an additional
>   condition before a pattern in a case is considered matched to the
>   control expression. If a guard expression is present, the statements
>   within the relevant case are executed only if the value of the control
>   expression matches one of the patterns of the case and the guard
>   expression evaluates to true.

**Documentation:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html

Comment: Thanks. "provide an **additional** condition" indicates it's it is evaluated after the pattern matching. It's confusing that the pattern matching part is just creating a variable. haha I'm clear now. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes it is a bit confusing that the pattern matching is simply assigning a variable, but they do that in order to always match that case (if the first case is not met) and then check the `guard` where clause. This way, if it does not match the where clause it will fail at matching the case pattern and fall out into the default case.